# Where's some good documentation for creating a GCC front end?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, frontend, bcpl

I've been tasked to come up with some half-year and full-year university projects for IT students and, due to the fact that it's hopefully never been done before (and also that I harbor certain sadistic tendencies), one of them is adding a BCPL front-end compiler to the GCC suite.

Where can I locate one or more of:

- some good reference-type documentation describing how to add such a beast to GCC?
- an example of doing so, for a simple language.
- any guides to the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go-lang's gccgo is a Go front end for gcc.  Here is the [announcement](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2009-11/msg00297.html).  I have not studied enough of Go to comment about its complexity or simplicity.  I hope for someone prepared to write a front end for gcc, gccgo should be a decent reference and/or example.

Comment: I don't think the asker wants source code as the answer to his/her question. Otherwise, he/she can just pull  the gcc source code and reads the content of gcc folder.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/GCC-Frontend-HOWTO.html is very old.

https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7884 is also very old.

https://thinkingeek.com/2016/01/05/tiny-gcc-front-part-1/ and https://thinkingeek.com/2016/01/06/tiny-gcc-front-part-2/ are much more recent.

I haven't read any of them.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Link 3 and 4 are very good.